# How do massively scalable sites like Facebook and Google implement sessions?

Tags: http, session, session-state

Does anyone have any insight into their system architecture?  Do they use Memcache?  Surely every time I click on Facebook my HTTP requests aren't being channeled to the same server where my session is in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic solution would be to store the session identifier & associated state in a database (or equivalent). This allows any application node in a cluster to access the session.

In practice, such a solution is slow and read-through caching (e.g. with Memcache), session replication, etc. are used to improve performance.